# How can I select from one table where the ID exists in one of two tables, but not in either of other two tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2005

This sounds confusing, but the idea is quite simple.

I want to get a list of products that have default rates, but a given 'Agent' doesn't have rates for. To do that, I need to select from the below table

```
    t_Products
|-ProductID-|--Product-|
|   100     | Product1 |
|   101     | Product2 |
|   102     | product3 |
|   103     | product4 |
```

Where the ID exists in either t_Annual_DefaultCost or t_Daily_DefaultCost

```
    t_Annual_DefaultCost
|-DefaultID-|-ProductID-|--Cost-|
|    100    |     100   | 24.00 |
|    101    |     101   | 26.00 |

    t_Daily_DefaultCost
|-DefaultID-|-ProductID-|--Cost-|-Days-|
|    100    |     100   | 24.00 |   1  |
|    101    |     100   | 26.00 |   2  |
|    102    |     102   | 22.50 |   2  |
|    103    |     102   | 97.50 |   8  |
```

But it cannot exist in either t_Annual_AgentCost or t_Daily_AgentCost for the given Agent ID

```
    t_Annual_AgentCost 
|---CostID--|-ProductID-|-AgentID-|--Cost-|
|    100    |    100    |  10001  | 24.00 |
|    101    |    100    |  10001  | 20.00 |

    t_Daily_AgentCost
|---CostID--|-ProductID-|-AgentID-|--Cost-|-Days-|
|    100    |     100   |  10001  | 24.00 |   1  |
|    102    |     102   |  10002  | 35.00 |   2  |
```

so for AgentID 10001 the end result should be

```
|-ProductID-|--Product-|
|   101     | product2 |
|   102     | product3 |
```

and for AgentID 10002 the end result should be

```
|-ProductID-|--Product-|
|   100     | product1 |
|   101     | product2 |
```

I'm currently using the below code to get a list of products that have default rates.
But I can't work out how to remove/not get the ones also in the AgentCost tables.

```
Select 
    distinct a.* 
from 
    t_Products as a
inner join
    ( 
        select 
            DefaultID ,ProductID
        from 
            t_Daily_DefalutCost 

        union 

        select 
            DefaultID , ProductID
        from 
            t_Annual_DefaultCost 
    ) 
    as b on a.ProductID = b.ProductID
```

Comment: When you say ID, please mention which ID. And, In statement "But it cannot exist in either t_Annual_AgentCost or t_Daily_AgentCost for the given Agent ID", do you mean to say "But it cannot exist in NEITHER t_Annual_AgentCost NOR t_Daily_AgentCost for the given Agent ID"?

Comment: Why should ProductID 103 show up for AgentID 10002, but not for AgentID 10001?

Comment: @galuano1 Where have I not said which ID? and yes I do mean the latter. I'll edit it now.

Comment: @GilM ProductID 103 should not show up for either AgentID I think I got confused whilst working that bit out. I'll edit it now.

Comment: @galuano1: I think you've caused a confusion. In English, you can say "... **cannot** ... **either** A **or** B ..." or you can say "... **can** ... **neither** A **nor** B ...". What you suggested was a double negative that probably didn't convey the right meaning in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to do one Agent at a time, then this is how I would do it:

```
SELECT
    a.* 
FROM
    t_Products As a
WHERE
    (   EXISTS( SELECT * FROM t_Daily_DefaultCost  As d WHERE d.ProductID = a.ProductID )
     OR EXISTS( SELECT * FROM t_Annual_DefaultCost As d WHERE d.ProductID = a.ProductID )
     )
AND NOT
    (   EXISTS( SELECT * FROM t_Daily_AgentCost    As d 
                WHERE d.ProductID = a.ProductID
                AND   d.AgentID   = @SpecifedAgentID )
     OR EXISTS( SELECT * FROM t_Annual_AgentCost   As d 
                WHERE d.ProductID = a.ProductID
                AND   d.AgentID   = @SpecifedAgentID )
     )
```

The `OR EXISTS`s here work pretty much the same as `UNION ALL SELECT`s would .

Answer (score 0):

I'd use this sort of approach.

```
select yourfields
from yourtables
where id in 
(

(select id
 from onetable
 union
 select id
 from anothertable)
 except
 (select id
  from yetanothertable
  union
  select id
  from thefinaltable)
)
```

You can fill in the actual table names.